# Use class variable in another class

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

Greetings everyone,

I'm currently working on an app using Python and wxPython.
In it I have a Dialog where several fields are filled in order to insert a "document" in a database.
The layout of that Dialog consists basically of a wx.Notebook, with several "tabs", each containing some sort of fields.

```
# Dialog class
class NovoRegisto(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title='Registar Nova O.T.', size=(900,600))

        painel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL)
        painel.SetScrollbars(0,30,0,500)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(painel)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        pag1 = InfoOT(notebook)
        pag2 = Avaliacao(notebook)
        pag3 = Componentes(notebook)
        pag4 = Material(notebook)
        pag5 = OTsRelacionadas(notebook)

                          <...>
        # function to insert data in SQLite database
        def OnRegister(self,event):
                          <...>

# first tab class
class InfoOT(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

                          <...>
```

As you can see, I have a class for the Dialog itself (with a definition controlled by a "Register" button) and then a different class for each of the "tabs" of the notebook.

Now, in order to submit the data to the database, I must have access to the "tabs" variables in the "OnRegister" definition (which belongs to the Dialog's class). However, I still haven't found a way to do that.

Can anyone help me? Do I have to change my program's structure? I did it this way because it was the only way I managed to make the notebook work...

Thank you in advance

Comment: @delnan, I think "tabs" just means pag1, pag2, etc.

Comment: @jambox, yes, you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "tabs" aren't class variables, they are local variables inside the function `__init__`. Also you don't want class variables, you want instance variables. To read and write instance variables you need to access them as attributes of `self`, for example `self1.pag1`, not by writing their name.

You need to distinguish between:

- function local variables - variables that you assign within a function
- class variables - class attributes that you access through the attribute operator (such as `NovoRegisto.variable_name`)
- instance variables - instance attributes that you access by using the attribute operator on `self` (such as `self.pag1`).

You should probably read more about how [Python classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) should be used.

As an additional note, you'd most often want to use

```
super(InfoOT, self).__init__(parent)
```

over

```
wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
```

which is available in new-style classes (i.e. all classes that indirectly or directly inherit from the builtin `object`)

Comment: He's also got def OnRegister inside the __init__ which confused the hell out of me...

Comment: @jambox, I realized now that I made a mistake about that while copying the code to the post. The def OnRegister is at the same level as the __init__

Comment: What's the reason for using super(..., self)?