# getting variable

Tags: python

I have kind of stupid question:

Is there any way to use instance variable from one class in another class?
I guess inheritance could be the way to do it, but I don't know how:(

for example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 12
        self.var2 = C()

    def start(self):
        self.var1=11
        B()

class B():

    def doSomething(self):
        varXX = "  here I would like to have objet self.var2 from A()"         

class C():
    def makeUI(self):
        something
```

thx for help

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845834/use-class-variable-in-another-class you should try to improve that question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 12
        self.var2 = C()

    def start(self):
        self.var1=11
        B(self)             # pass this instance into the initialisation of B

class B():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a          # save reference to the A() instance

    def doSomething(self):
        varXX = self.a.var2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to use instance variable from one class in another class? No You can't. Instance variable are object specific and not class specific. Either you need to have an access to the object of the Class or you have a design problem. You probably need to make them class variables.

If these variables are not instance specific, make them class variables and access as follows

```
>>> class A():
    _init_done = False
    def __init__(self):
        if not A._init_done:
            A.var1 = 12
            A.var2 = C()
            A._init_done = True
def start(self):
    A.var1=11
    B()            
>>> class B():    
    def doSomething(self):
        print A.var1           
>>> class C():
    def makeUI(self):
        something            
>>> x = A()
>>> y = B()
>>> y.doSomething()
12
>>> x.start()
>>> y.doSomething()
11
```

Comment: This runs, but is a strange concept. Every time I create an instance of `A()`, the `A.var2` is updated to a new instance of `C()`. Not sure what you would use that for

Comment: @gnibbler: I just extended a concept of using Class Variables. In case you want not to create a new instance(), you can just easily add a flag to check for first time initialization. I have updated my answer